# React.js file. Socket.io file inclusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

In my react.js project I needed to include socket.io support. For that I have used a this [repository](https://github.com/DanialK/ReactJS-Realtime-Chat) as a reference.

That worked, but on other machines when the code is pulled is giving the error that the socket.io is undefined in the browser.

This is the main index.html that has the socket inclusion:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.built.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is how it is used in the React component:

```
var Select = require('react-select');
var socket = io.connect();

const PartsCleanUp = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
  location: React.PropTypes.object,
  routeParams: React.PropTypes.any,
  children: React.PropTypes.object
},
```

What I dont understand is, inside the index.html file... how is socket io being fetched? I assume it is being injected with webpack or somehow.

I am thinking that I need a standalone socket.io to be included in the index.html, but I am not certain.

Picture shows inclusion in the index.html and that the socket is installed as node_module.[image]

Comment: Are you doing it with node.js in server side?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You don't need to include socket.io if you are using a module bundler like webpack or browserify

Comment: I have included file socket.io as a dependancy inside main index.html and it seeme to be working. But I am wondering why it did not work initially?